# Drupal redirecting to https while trying to login

Tags: drupal, redirect, authentication, https, upgrade

When I try to login drupal website is redirecting to https and page is not available. I am not able to access websites any page with https. Can any body help. I want to login with http. I upgraded site fron drupal 6 to drupal 7. Drupal 6 site logins without https.

Comment: I think you have to have some module which is forcing you to connect via https, or there is some misconfiguration in settings.php file. Can you post list of modules?

Comment: Check your settings.php file and see it you have $conf['http'] = true; or if you have the secure_pages module enabled.

Comment: I installed secure login module. I tried by disabling it. But no effect. THere is no such $conf['http']=true; line in settings.php. Any way I started doing it again.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed new modules before getting the error, please disable them from system table. Make sure none of you custom module, if any, tries to access https if its not available on the site. Most of the time, this is a minor configuration error.